# Bluetooth connection issues

Tags: wireless, sound, bluetooth, 22.04

Since I updated to Ubuntu 22.04, Bluetooth has been broken, and I cannot seem to connect my Bose QuietComfort 2 to my laptop.

My headphones are most of the time plainly refusing to connect, and the rare times I manage to connect them, they just disconnect or play garbled sounds.

I tried:

- messing with the `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file and putting Bluetooth to bredr;
- pairing through the bluetoothctl command;
- unpairing and pairing them again;
- using Blueman.

My laptop is a Lenovo IdeaPad 5 pro.

Result of the `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7961]
DeviceName: Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:e0bc]
Kernel driver in use: mt7921e

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:56fb IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0489:e0cd Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having trouble with Bose Soundlink2, the following worked for me.
I was using Ubuntu 20.? and then migrated to 22.04. The same thing fixed the newer OS version. Also I had issues with volume but in 22.04 it seems to have been fixed for me.

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

Now, install bluez-tools : https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/bluez-tools

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y bluez-tools

bt-device -r <mac address bluetooth speaker>
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having problems pairing my Beats Fit Pro headphones to my brand new Dell XPS 13 Pro laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.1. I tried a lot of different solutions from forums but nothing worked. I ended up fixing my connection issues by manually editing the `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file in a terminal window. I'm not sure if this just coincidentally fixed my pairing issues or if this makes sense to someone more familiar than I am with Linux. All I know is that it allowed me to connect my headphones to my laptop.

**Steps**

1. `sudo vim /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`
2. Uncomment and update line 65 to `FastConnectable = true`
3. Try repairing (successfully)
4. [Optional] Run `sudo vim /etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and update line 65 to `FastConnectable = false` if you don't want FastConnect enabled

Comment: This worked for me. Just set to true then turn bluetooth off and on again.

Comment: Doesn't work for Ubuntu 22.04 with Sony

Comment: Worked for me on 23.04 only after reboot

Answer (score 0):

I have also struggled to play any sound on my Sony WF1000XM3
[image]

It appeared to be connected, but I cannot hear the notification from my headphone.

Sound settings output devices and `pavulcontrol` don't show my headphone either.
I searched for some solution and tried reconfigure pulse for weeks but none of that work.

And here is how I fixed it. First, find the device MAC and unregister it.

```
bluetoothctl
#devices
Device 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E LE_WF-1000XM3
#remove 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E ServicesResolved: no
Device has been removed
```

Start pairing on my headphone (touching 2 buds for a few seconds in my case).

```
#scan on
# pair 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E                                       <<<
Attempting to pair with 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E Modalias: usb:v054Cp0CE0d0312
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E ServicesResolved: yes           <<<
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E Paired: yes                     <<<
Pairing successful                                             
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E ServicesResolved: no            <<<
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E Connected: no                   <<<
# connect 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E                                    <<<
Attempting to connect to 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E Connected: yes         
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:3B:08:2E ServicesResolved: yes           <<<
```

If you don't see `[CHG] Device <MAC> ServicesResolved: yes` after a few seconds. Try `connect` command again until it is connected.

Answer (score -1):

"bt-device -r "

The finding that mac address requires that you are already paired to the device.