# Sound not working through speakers, but works through headphones Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04, alsa

I clean installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop device in a dualboot set up with Windows 10 about 2 weeks ago. Everything was working fine until a couple of days ago when I noticed no sound was being outputted.

The "Balance" bar under Sound settings menu moved to indicate sound was being played and received as normal.  Output device listed as "Built in audio". No matter how loud the volume is, I still get no sound.

When I dual boot into Windows, sound works perfectly with no issues.

I have tried everything on [this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) guide from Itsfoss (force reloading Alsa, starting Pulse audio, resetting Pulse audio config settings, everything in Alsamixer looks fine etc).

The "inxi -SMA" command returns the following under audio:

> Audio:
>
> Device-1: Intel Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
> Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-47-generic running: yes
> Sound
> Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
> Sound Server-3:
> PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes

My PC specs:
HP Pavilion 15
Running Ubuntu 22.04.1

Just looking for ideas on how to diagnose and fix this issue.

Comment: Have you disabled Fast Startup in Windows? It's a must when dual-booting. Try again after disabling it and shutting down Windows before booting into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [guide](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) that you mentioned, `sudo alsa force-reload` and then rebooting worked for me! Thanks!

**My problem** was my headset and my speakers would connect but wouldn't play sound from Google Chrome or Spotify. Both devices are bluetooth. However, they would play *system sounds* and sounds from *local video files* played through the VLC media player.

**I also tried** following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407083/bluetooth-connection-issues-ubuntu-22-04) using bluez-tools and editing `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`, but I had no success. I suggest you try it, as it worked for some people.

I use Ubuntu 22.04 kernel 5.15.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling ubuntu or check your sound card if you use build-in sound check If it works in windows 10 and  that does not work contact ubuntu support

Comment: Welcome to AU. That doesn’t really answer the question.